# how to send test request to usps test server to access ZipCodeLookup API?

Tags: xml, request, coldfusion-8

i have registered myself with **usps.com/webtools** and get username/password.
when i am sending test request to usps test server, i am getting error "**Error getting USERID attribute**"

`http://testing.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=[API_Name]&XML=[XML_String_containing_User_ID]"`

i am sending request like this (userid is dummy in this case)

`http://testing.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=ZipCodeLookup&XML=<userid>018BITOC5420</userid>`

how to sent test request with xml userid?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=ZipCodeLookup&XML=<ZipCodeLookupRequest USERID="xxxxxxx"><Address ID="0"><Address1></Address1><Address2>6406 Ivy Lane</Address2><City>Greenbelt</City><State>MD</State></Address></ZipCodeLookupRequest>
```

Source: https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-v3-1d.htm

Comment: FWIW, the sign-up instructions from USPS are *awful*, referencing links and documents that don't exist on the page referenced. They should just include a direct link to this documentation on the sign-up email or attach it as a PDF.

Comment: Thanks Sharondio, it is done now, i was also following same Development Guide and made some test requests but i was getting error saying "ZipCodeLookup  is not a valid API name for this protocol".

Comment: Great It working fine , thank you if anybody face problem read https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-v3-1d.htm#_Toc131231413 OR https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/development-guide-v3-1c.pdf